# Execute Reader is not recognized in MySql.Data.Client

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating cross platform app and in a class for database connection, execute reader, scalar, conn.open(), conn.close() and others are not recognized. I'm getting error stating "References to type 'Component" claims in it defined in system, but it is not found". I have downloaded MySql.Data nuget and added all the reference need for MySql and I have no idea what causing this issue. Please help.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Camera
{
     public class DBConn
    {
        private static MySqlConnection getDBConn()
        {
        string testDB;
        //connection string with database location
        //change the database location in following line
        testDB = "Server = myip; Port = myport; database = readingmeterdb; User Id = root; Password = mypassword; charset = utf8";

        return new MySqlConnection(testDB);
    }

    public static List<machines> getmachine()
    {
        List<machines> machinelist = new List<machines>();
        MySqlConnection mydbconn = getDBConn();
        string qry = "SELECT * FROM machines";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, mydbconn);

        try
        {
            mydbconn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myrdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myrdr.Read())
            {
                machines machine = new machines(int.Parse(myrdr["machineId"].ToString()), myrdr["machineDesc"].ToString());
                machinelist.Add(machine);
            }
            return machinelist;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }

        finally {
            mydbconn.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Why you don't use SqlCliente instead of MySqlClient?

Comment: try using mysql.data as well as mysql.data.client

Comment: @Rekcs I though SqlClient is for MS SQL server??

Comment: @BugFinder that should fix it.

Comment: I just added MySql.Data, still no luck. it is not even using that

Comment: I think the problem is not with MySql.Data.Client. I just changed and used System.Data.SqlClient, it shows the same error. What it could be?

Comment: I've just tested your code in my Visual Studio and it works without any problem.